RTK Query after invalidation it still uses old cache data
After deletion of the cached data I have to make 2 calls

getUserContacts
getAllUsersContacts

The second call getAllUsersContacts successfully updates the cache data but the first call shows in the network tab that it uses cache data that was been created before deletion.
Here is my serviceApi
getAllUsersContacts: builder.query({
  query: ({ params}) => ({
    url: 'users/contacts',
    params
  }),
  providedTags: (result, error, arg) => 
   result
          ? [
              ...result._embedded.users
                .map((user) => [...user.contacts.map(({ id }) => ({ type: 'Contact' as const, id }))])
                .flat(6),
              { type: 'Contact', id: 'LIST' }
            ]
          : [{ type: 'Contact', id: 'LIST' }]
}),
getUserContacts: builder.query({
  query: ({params}) => ({
    url: 'user/contacts',
    params
  }),
  providesTags: (result, error, arg) =>
        result
          ? [
              ...result.contacts.map(({ id }) => ({ type: 'Contact' as const, id })),
              { type: 'Contact', id: 'LIST' }
            ]
          : [{ type: 'Contact' }]
}),
deleteContact: builder.mutation({
  query: ({id}) => ({
    url: 'contacts/${id}'
    method: 'DELETE'
  }),
  invalidatesTags: (result, error, arg) => [{ type: 'Contact', id: arg.id }]
})

Call getUserContacts is made on component render and based on the selected user from dropdown
const {data, isFetching} = useGetUserContacts({params: {userName: user?.name}}, {skip: !user})

And the call getUsersContacts is made from another component
const {data, isFetching} = useGetUsersContacts({params})

I was thinking that my tags are not correct but it seems like they invalidate correctly so rtk-query makes call getUsersContacts and getUserContacts.
The calls order:

delete {id}       status 200   response from server
getUserContacts   status 200   response from cache
getUsersContacts  status 2oo   response from server

Also I am thinking to use async onQueryStarted on the deletion but it looks like there is only cases to update or create endpoints.

You might need to invalidate the tag for getUserContacts explicitly in the deleteContact mutation. For instance, if getUserContacts uses the tag { type: 'Contact', id: 'LIST' }, make sure this is included in the invalidation:
deleteContact: builder.mutation({
  query: ({ id }) => ({
    url: `contacts/${id}`,
    method: 'DELETE',
  }),
  invalidatesTags: (result, error, arg) => [
    { type: 'Contact', id: arg.id },
    { type: 'Contact', id: 'LIST' }  // Ensure 'LIST' is invalidated
  ],
}),


Thank you for your answer. I am successfully invalidating on the deletion and as result the call getUserContacts triggered after the delete operation BUT instead of call API it uses cache.
